# How to load web user control dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

This is really important question. this makes me crazy in 4 hours :( i can load UCAddX.ascx but if i click "Search in X" button not load UCSearchX user control. There are 3 button also there are 3 web user control. i want to load these 3 web user controls after clickEvents. But below method not working.How to load web user control dynamically? Click By Click (Like Tab control)

```
 public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["controlType"] = "AddX";
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                AddUserControl();
            }
            else
            {
                AddUserControl();
            }
        }

        protected void btnAddX_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["controlType"] = "AddX";
            if (!IsPostBack)
                  AddUserControl();
            else
                AddUserControl();
        }

        protected void btnSearchX_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["controlType"] = "SearchX";
            if (!IsPostBack)
                AddUserControl();
            else
                AddUserControl();

        }
        protected void btnUpdateX_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void AddUserControl()
        {
          //  plhContent1.Controls.Clear();
            if (ViewState["controlType"] != null)
            {
                if (ViewState["controlType"].ToString() == "AddX")
                {
                    UCAddX uc = (UCAddX)Page.LoadControl("~/Pages/EN/MyUserControls/UCAddX.ascx");
                    uc.ID = "ucAddX";
                    uc.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server");
                    uc.EnableViewState = true;
                    uc.Visible = true;
                    plhContent1.Controls.Add(uc);
                }
                else if (ViewState["controlType"].ToString() == "SearchX")
                {
                    UCSearchX uc = (UCSearchX)Page.LoadControl("~/Pages/EN/MyUserControls/UCSearchX.ascx");
                    uc.ID = "ucSearchX";
                    uc.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server");
                    uc.EnableViewState = true;
                    uc.Visible = true;
                    plhContent1.Controls.Add(uc);
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: In your button click events, I think it is too late to modify ViewState.  You probably need Session state instead.

Comment: First of all, I don't think 4 hours is to much for an important problem to solve or get mad or crazy.I remember several problems which took me weeks to solve.And secondly, instead of loading those user controls dynamically I'd rather put them in different ASP.NET's `Panel` controls and tickle their `Visibility` properties, which I'm not sure if it is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this,

```
//to load the control
     protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         ViewState["controlType"] = "AddSector";
         //you don't need to check the if condiontion, cause you load every time the controls
         AddUserControl();
      }
```

when you need to get values from the control after postback you should get it on

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventsArgs args) {
    //your placeholder that contains data
}
```

Comment: i dont understand protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventsArgs args) {
    //your placeholder that contains data
}

Comment: here you get the data that contained in the controls that exists in the controls, because the prerender event happens almost the last, you wont be able to see the values before that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to load usercontrol dynamically

```
var control = LoadControl(filePath) as ControlType;
```

then you can subscribe to events and add to control placeholder.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Penguen Why do you store info in a ViewState instead of passing it into the add control method? void AddUserControl(Type controlType)

Comment: @Penguen btw. You are calling AddUserControl method on pageLoad and on button click... does that mean you are trying to add 2 controls with the same ID???

Answer (score 0):

User controls when loaded dynamically need to be loaded on every Page_Load so their view state is maintained. So you need something like:

```
    public string CurrentControlToLoad
    {
        get
        {
             if(ViewState["controlType"] == null)
                 return "";
             return (string)ViewState["controlType"];
        }
        set
        {
             ViewState["controlType"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(CurrentControlToLoad != "")
           LoadControl(CurrentControlToLoad);
    }

    protected void btnAddSector_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentControlToLoad = "AddSector";
        LoadControl(CurrentControlToLoad);
    }
```